# Laptop battery lasts significantly shorter than it should

Tags: battery, thinkpad

A few days ago I bought a refurbished ThinkPad x201i with the following specs.

- i3 processor
- 250GB hard drive, 7200rpm
- 2GB RAM
- Runs Ubuntu 12.04  with xfce.
- Screen brightness set to around 50% most of the time.
- Things that I usually have running: a few files on emacs (mostly TeX, sometimes Python or C), a couple bash shells, a few pdf files, firefox with rarely more than 6-8 tabs (gmail, facebook, job-related websites without video or other power-hungry things), dropbox.

Battery capacity is specified as 28.8 Wh. Running `upower` reveals that actual capacity is still 28.7 Wh. With this setup, and based on reviews like [this](http://www.notebookreview.com/notebookreview/lenovo-thinkpad-x201-review/) and threads likes [this](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/x201i-battery-life-6-cell.483261/), I would expect a full charge to last about 3 or 4 hours. In reality, I'm lucky if I can go 90 minutes before the battery gets critically low. I have to take longish train rides about twice a week, so having a battery that drains so fast is a potentially big problem. I could potentially plug the laptop into one of the train outlets (yay for Deutsche Bahn ICE), but I'd rather understand why the battery drains so fast to begin with.

Comment: Buying a new battery from ebay etc is not that inexpensive. I have both originals and others for the laptops in my company (x61s, T410s, T420, T530). Originals are of course the best but for older machines the "others" work fine.

Comment: You might want to purchase an external battery pack with AC outlet or universal 12V outlet laptop charger.

Comment: 28 watt-hours are not that much. Isn't there a larger battery pack variant for your laptop? Let's say 72 Wh?

Answer (score 5):

Install and run powertop (sudo apt-get install powertop) to see what is utilizing your power resources and what you can do to tune it.

Its very difficult to make Linux as power efficient as Windows where laptops are not designed around it.

Also, a guess - your system only has 2 gigs of RAM, so its probably swapping quite a bit - and the 250 gig hard drive is probably eating a fair amount of your juice if its spinning up all the time.  You may want to play with vm.swappiness to reduce the amount of swapping it does (and increase performance in many cases !).

Also, check that you don't have things like Bluetooth, Wifi on, as these will drain the battery.

Sorry, but also note that your system has a first generation i3 processor.  These are very power hungry relative to newer ones - Intel only really started pushing power savings after these came out.  Using CPU frequency scaling can help, but you are still dealing with a chip based on 32 nm lithography and a 35 watt TDP (compare to i3-4020Y on 22nm and 11.5 W tdp, designed to run arround 6 watts and giving better performance).   Not much you can do about the elephant in the room.

Comment: Also, although I use firefox pretty exclusively, I expect that switching to Chrome will improve your battery life.  Firefox eats a lot of resources - Chrome has a reputation for being more lightweight.

Comment: Also, looking at https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/pd009552 - you seem to be comparing your system with a (4 cell) 28.8 Wh batteries with reviews with systems with (6 cell) 56.2 Wh batteries - this also explains the difference in battery life.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu, in my opinion, is power hungry. This may be an issue but, to be honest, your system should last longer than that unless you are keeping your processing up via Python for long periods. This could be a reason since most of the times we run not only the interpreter but also query some Mongos/Sqlites or got an Apanche running on the background, maybe an IDE , etc.
Acording to this [not so useful source because it´s in spanish](http://www.notebookcheck.org/Analisis-del-portatil-Lenovo-ThinkPad-X201.34323.0.html) your machine new should last 129 minutes on full charge and full processing.
For me this is a case where i would run some tests over the battery. Also, consider this is a refurbished computer so considering that it´s should perform as a new one is not an option.
I think you should try something like bateryeater to check your battery response and continue from there.